# Resolve 500 server error with Google Core Reporting API

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am at a complete loss at this point on how to resolve my query issue. We have been using the R package, RGA, for about a year now without any problems. I have a script that has been fetching data from 7 views, matching sessions based off of specific pages on our website and totaling them to our product offerings.

This has been working without problem for months. Out of nowhere I have been getting 503 and 500 internal server errors and I'm not sure why.

I've tried changing the fetch.by status to "month", "quarter", "year", "day", etc... but I think the initial query is just too big.

I've also tried changing the max.results options and fetching just one profile ID at a time. We have 7 to process.

```
date1 <- as.character(cut(Sys.Date(), "month"))
date1_name <- format(as.Date(date1), format = '%Y%m')

date2 <- as.character(Sys.Date())
date2_name <- format(as.Date(date2), format = '%Y%m')


dimensions <-  c("ga:yearMonth"
)
metrics <-  c("ga:sessions"
)

filters2 <- "ga:sessions>0"


#fetch trip level data for all users and for the micro-goal segment
# country_short_table

short_unq <- unique(country_short_table$destination)
brand_trip_unique <- unique(trip_country_brand$brand_trip)

brand_trip=1
brand_trip=73

all_sessions <- data.frame()
for (brand_trip in 1:length(brand_trip_unique)){
  mkt <- gsub('_.*', '', brand_trip_unique[brand_trip])
  trip <- gsub('.*_', '', brand_trip_unique[brand_trip])
  id <- as.character(ids[ids$market==mkt, 'id'])

  segment <- paste('ga:pagePath=~(reisen|circuit)/.*/', trip, sep = '')
  segment_def <- paste('users::condition::',segment,sep = '')

  table <- get_ga(profileId = id,
                  start.date = date1,
                  end.date = date2,
                  metrics = metrics, 
                  dimensions = dimensions
                  ,filters = filters2
                  ,segment = segment_def
                  ,samplingLevel = "HIGHER_PRECISION"
                  ,fetch.by = "quarter"
                  ,max.results = NULL
  )

  if (is.list(table)==T) {
        table$trip <- trip
        table$market <- mkt
        all_sessions <- bind_rows(all_sessions, table)
  } else {
        next()
  }


}
```

**GOAL:** Can you recommend any way that I could avoid this issue, maybe by separating the date queries and cycling them by weeks or days of the month? I need monthly data aggregated every day but I'm not sure how to edit this script I inherited.

Comment: 503 means server not available. Try later? If the problem persists, provide a minimal reprodcucible example.

Comment: We also noticed an increase of 500 and 503 errors today.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. But then I tried it outside of my office, at home wifi, and it worked just fine. Are there cases where internet providers throttle exposure to google apis?